# Python 2.6 doesn't throw Assertion Error before parsing the entire script

Tags: python, assertion

I'm using a simple code in Python to assert the new version before proceeding. Here is the code:-

```
import sys
assert sys.version_info >= (3, 5)
print(f"New formatting style")
```

Running that code through the Python 2.6 interpreter returns a SyntaxError as follows:-

```
  File "test.py", line 3
    print(f"New formatting style")
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I was expecting an AssertionError. Any workaround? My goal is to display a user-friendly message that the Python version is not supported.

Comment: FWIW, f-strings were introduced in Python **3.6**, so the assert should be `> (3, 5)` or `>= (3, 6)`

Comment: Can't reproduce on 2.7.16: https://repl.it/repls/StickyMountainousOctagons

Comment: Couldn't find any Python 2.6 interpreter online as it is probably too old. Why are you trying to support such an old version of Python? Anyway, try `print sys.version_info` to see what it returns

Comment: @DeepSpace The problem is that if there is an f-string anywhere in the script, you get a syntax error from that instead of an assertion error.

Comment: f-strings won't work for python 2.7 and below version. { .format } method works with Python 2.7 and below versions.

Comment: Syntax check happens during compilation to bytecode - which happens before execution (where the assertion would take place)

Comment: Yes, I hope no one uses that old version of Python but just in case someone uses it, I wanted to have some warning. But no big deal. Hopefully in the next few months all systems would be updated to at least v3.7

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes, you can find one. and there is one. You can try "repl.it/languages" they have python 2.7 version.

Comment: @rdas Thanks. I believe that explains it. We can close this case. Thank you all for your inputs.

Comment: @trojanatwar I know, if you re-read my comment you will see that I linked to an example that runs on Python 2.7. I was referring to Python 2.6

Comment: @khelwood Indeed, I was focused on the assertion rather than the SyntaxError I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the Python interpreter is tokenising the code before executing any statements.

One work around is to separate your worker code into a different module, and put just a warning in the main.py

e.g.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info < (3, 5):
    print("Sorry requires Python 3.6 or greater")
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    import MyCoreModule
    MyCoreModule.main()
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. I'll certainly use that method for complex scripts.